# Why isn't there inplace flag in F.sigmoid in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

Both `relu`, `leakyrelu` have `inplace` flag, so why not `sigmoid`?

```
Signature: F.sigmoid(input)

F.relu(input, inplace=False)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to docs:

> `nn.functional.sigmoid` is deprecated. Use `torch.sigmoid` instead.

If you need in-place version, use `sigmoid_`:

```py
import torch
torch.manual_seed(0)

a = torch.randn(5)

print(a)

a.sigmoid_()

print(a)
```

```py
tensor([ 1.5410, -0.2934, -2.1788,  0.5684, -1.0845])
tensor([0.8236, 0.4272, 0.1017, 0.6384, 0.2527])
```

[sigmoid docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=sigmoid#torch.sigmoid)